# Creating a class with static pointers to explicitly loaded DLL functions

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport

I want to have multiple instances of a DLLInterface class but as each object will have pointers to the same DLL functions I want these to be static.

The below code doesn't compile. (I do have a reason for needing multiple instances containing the same pointers which the stripped down code below doesn't illustrate.)

```
//Header file:

typedef void (*DLLFunction)();
class DLLInterface
{
private:
    static HINSTANCE hinstDLL;
public:
    static DLLFunction Do;

    DLLInterface()
    {
        if(!hinstDLL || !Do)
        {
            hinstDLL = LoadLibrary("DoubleThink.dll");
            Do = (DLLFunction)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "Do");
        }
    }
};
```

I need to have all code contained within this header file also. (I know I can make it compile by adding statements like the following into a cpp file on the EXE but I need to avoid doing this.

> HINSTANCE DLLInterface::hinstDLL = 0;

Thanks!

Comment: Errors like the following: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static struct HINSTANCE__ * DLLInterface::hinstDLL" (?hinstDLL@DLLInterface@@0PAUHINSTANCE__@@A)
1>c:\Users\Anonymous\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DoubleThink\Debug\ConsoleDemo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick I can think of is to use templates.  The idea is you make the class the includes the static data a template class and then derive your actual class from it with some specific type:

```
template <class T>
class DLLInterfaceImpl;
{
private:
    static HINSTANCE hinstDLL;
public:
    static DLLFunction Do;
};

template <class T>
HINSTANCE DllInterfaceImpl<T>::hInstDLL;

template <class T>
DLLFunction DllInterfaceImpl<T>::Do;

class DllInterface : public DllInterfaceImpl<int>
{
};
```

Because DllInterfaceImpl is a template, you can put your static definitions in the header file and the compiler will do some "tricks" so that multiple definitions do not cause the link to fail.

Comment: Wow works just like you said. I don't think I ever would have come across this answer myself. Thanks!